# Как настроить Namespace на PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

При загрузке проекта PhpStorm предложил установить  Namespace или дать ему это сделать автоматически.  Нажала - Автоматически.
В результате имею ошибку связанную с Namespace.

Namespace 'jdoc' is not bound

Подскажите, как задать правильно настройки Namespace? 
[image: Namespace]

p.s. Проект на joomla, работающий, изначально ошибок в нем не было. Поэтому редактировать namespace в коде не вижу смысла

Answer (score 0):

Используйте File->Settings->Languages & Frameworks. На картинке WordPress, но выше есть и Joomla! Support. Без каких-либо плагинов для Joomla.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Использую. Joomla! Support действительно избавила проект от большого количества ошибок связанных с определением классов и переменных. Но ‘jdoc’ PhpStorm по прежнему не видит. Namespace 'jdoc' is not bound.  Учитывая, что константа jdoc – основа joomla, - этой ошибкой все забито.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки, связанные с `namespace` пропали после команды `Code > Detect PSR-0 namespace roots`.